# Fortigate 60D slow internet speed without DMZ

Tags: firewall, router, fortigate

I am not getting the full internet speed through LAN ports. Only around 130Mb instead of 230Mb. Only way to get 230Mb is plug into the DMZ port. All settings are default. All LAN ports are 1000Mbit Full just like DMZ port. Is there something I can do to speed up LAN ports?

Comment: What did Fortigate support say?

Comment: I don't have support plan with them.

Answer (score 1):

Already resolved. Limiting factor was because of software switch interface. Changed it to hardware switch for LAN ports. Speed is where it should be now.

Answer (score 0):

Isolate your lan network from firewall and connect laptop to lan interface assign network setting ipaddress ,subnet , mask and test internet speed test in laptop . By this way you can find actuall and correct internet isp speed  . Further check with continuous ping command ping Google and check any packet drops or any latency in ping request and responce(ping -t) if you find any abnormality share data with isp and check with him.